# Why member ring is favoured in chelates?

Tags: coordination-compounds

why chelates which form 3 or 4 member rings or 6 or 7 member rings are as stable as 5 member ring chelates? 
for example if we measure stability of chelates with oxygen donors, say oxalate, malonate, succinate etc oxalate chelated with metal shoes more stability. why malonate , succinate as chelating ligands are less stable?

Comment: Chelating increases the stability , probably due to more change in positive entropy

Answer (score 1):

In its **general** form, your statement on the stability of these complexes is wrong!

$\ce{Be(II)}$-malonato complexes are more stable than the corresponding oxalato complexes, cf. [*Preparative, potentiometric and NMR studies of the interaction of beryllium(II) with oxalate and malonate*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0020-1693(97)05520-5).

Comment: no sir i was not trying to say it was universal, i saw in books that said 5 member ring forming chelates are relatively more stable than 6 member or 7 member or 4 member ring forming chelates.